# CKEditor: how to apply classes (instead of inline styles) to content

Tags: css, class, ckeditor

For CKeditor, is there a way to have it apply a class name instead of a style? So instead of doing:

```
<span style="color: #ffffff;">Text</span>
```

It would do:

```
<span class="white">Text</span>
```

Simplified to make more sense, but except for the typical bold/italics/underline, we need to be able to use variables in a SCSS sheet for consistency and multiple clients. This would not be something picked from a custom style list - it needs to be automatic when people click on existing toolbar options. Has anyone managed something like this?

Comment: Just check [this tutorial](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_howtos_styles), should be simple.

Comment: @skobaljic Thank you, but as I said to the answer below, I don't want to make people pick a style from a list, I would like it to be automatic when people click to the toolbar options. I am updating my original question to try and clarify.

Comment: You would have to create your own tools I think, or edit existing one. Each tool is an addon in separate folder (look at not-compressed source files of CKEditor) - it is easy to find files and to edit them, those programmers are good.

Comment: Hey! Have You found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this code in your config.js file:

```
    config.stylesSet = [
    { name: 'CSS White', element: 'span', attributes: { 'class': 'white' } }
]
```

It will show you a 'CSS White' option in the style select field of your ceditor.

Comment: I knew about the style options, but I don't want people to have to pick a style. I would like those classes to be added automatically when people pick things in the toolbars already there. Like in my original example, if they pick the color above, it would do a class instead doing the hex code in an inline style.

Comment: Its like use justifyRight and it add class justifyRight instead of style="text-alight: right;"

Comment: @Hitokage Did you guys ever solve this. Looking to do the same thing. Not use "styles" but have it just auto use styles for classes rather than inline. Like tadeusz said.